# select only last 6 month from jquery monthpicker

Tags: jquery

Hi I am trying to display last 6 month records and I am using jQuery month picker(not the date picker) and I want to disable remaining months

For that, i used following code it works perfectly but if click again it enables only the current year to enable months and I am using disable months function in month picker.

Start year, end year and months to disable those and all I am getting from backend  PHP file

//code...

```
       $(document).ready(function(){

   $(function() {
    $("#month_year").monthpicker(
                {
                pattern:'mmm yyyy',
                selectedYear: Startyear,
                startYear: Startyear,
                finalYear: Endyear,
                }
        );
//alert(Startyear);
        $('#month_year').monthpicker().on('click monthpicker-change-year', function (e, year) {

        if(Startyear===Endyear){

           $('#month_year').monthpicker('disableMonths', [{% for key,     enter code herevalue in dismon %} {{key}}, {% endfor %}]); 
        }
        else{
            if(year==Startyear){

                $('#month_year').monthpicker('disableMonths', [{% for value in startyearmonthenable %} {{value}}, {% endfor %}]); 
            }else{
                $('#month_year').monthpicker('disableMonths', [{% for value in endyearmonthenable %} {{value}}, {% endfor %}]);

           }
     }
 }); 
});
```

please anybody tell me how should I make it work...